# Hide/Show element with javascript generated by XSL

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

I have a xml file containing some data. I would like to display an "extended" view of the data or an overview. I manage to display the extended view with XSL and I am not fighting with javascript to hide some content for the overview.

Here is my xml file:

```
<BS>
<project>
    <name>project1</name>
    <references id="1">
        <ref>ref1</ref>
        <ref>ref2</ref>
        <ref>ref3</ref>
    </references>

    <references id="2">
        <ref>ref4</ref>
        <ref>ref5</ref>
        <ref>ref6</ref>
    </references>

</project>
<project>
    <name>project2</name>
    <references id="1">
        <ref>ref7</ref>
        <ref>ref8</ref>
        <ref>ref9</ref>
    </references>
</project>
</BS>
```

and my XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<html xsl:version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function HideClass(matchClass)
    {
    var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('*'),i;
    for (i in elems)
        {
        if((elems[i].className).indexOf(matchClass) > -1)
            {
            elems[i].style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
    }

function ShowClass(matchClass)
    {
    var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('*'),i;
    for (i in elems)
        {
        if((elems[i].className).indexOf(matchClass) > -1)
            {
            elems[i].style.display = 'block';
            }
        }
    }

function ShowOverview()
    {
    var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('*'),i;
    for (i in elems)
        {
        if((elems[i].className).indexOf('id1') > -1)
            {
            elems[i].style.display = 'block';
            }
        else
            {
            elems[i].style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
    }
</script>
 </head>        

 <body>

<xsl:for-each select="BS/project">
    <h3><xsl:attribute name="class"><xsl:value-of select="name"/>-id1</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
    </h3>


    <xsl:for-each select="references">
        <div><xsl:attribute name="class"><xsl:value-of select="name"/>-id<xsl:value-of select="@id"/></xsl:attribute>

        Status: OK<br/>
        References id: <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
        <table> 
            <xsl:for-each select="ref">
                <tr><td>
                <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
                </td></tr> 
            </xsl:for-each> 
        </table>
        </div>
        <br/>
    </xsl:for-each>


    <!-- link Hide-->
    <xsl:element name="a">
    <xsl:attribute name="href">#</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="onclick">HideClass('<xsl:value-of select="name"/>');return false;</xsl:attribute>
    <i><xsl:text>Hide </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="name"/></i>
    </xsl:element>
    <!-- end of link -->
    <br/>
    <!-- link Show-->
    <xsl:element name="a">
    <xsl:attribute name="href">#</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="onclick">ShowClass('<xsl:value-of select="name"/>');return false;</xsl:attribute>
    <i><xsl:text>Show </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="name"/></i>
    </xsl:element>
    <!-- end of link -->
    <br/>

</xsl:for-each>
<hr/>
<a href="#" onclick="ShowOverview();return false;"> Show only overview</a>


</body>
</html>
```

But it does not work. I would like to display everything on "load page" (this is working!)  and to hide the project 1 (and all its content) while clicking on "Hide project1".

Moreover, I would like to display an "overview of all projects" with:

- the title (ex < h3 > Project 1 < /h3 > )
- the first references (with status, ref id=1 and the table containing the ref)

for each project while clicking on "Show only overview".

But my XSL can only display everything, hide everything or hide just the title !??!

Do you have any ideas how I can achieve my goal?

Thank you.

Comment: An XSLT transformation cannot "hide" or "display". It generates output (XML, HTML or just text). I think that you want to generate HTML+Javascript so that when displayed and a particular button clicked, you want to have a corresponding "Show/Hide" visual effect. Therefore, you need to determine what HTML+Javascript combination has the wanted behavior -- this is a pure Javascript question. Only then, you need to solve the problem how to produce the so determined HTML+Javascript from the source XML that you have.

Comment: Your style-sheet must have as its root element, <xsl:stylesheet>, but you have <html>. Something is amiss here.

Comment: Hi @julie, as Dimitre Novatchev says, in this stage you really have a HTML+JavaScript question. The xslt part comes after you solve that little gem. What I would do is: 1. create an html with static dummy data and super-cool JavaScript that behaves exactly as you want it to. 2. Split this gem up into html, css and javascript part if not already done so. 3. start thinking about xslt: define the input document (the output is your html) and give transformations a go to bridge the gap in between. I'm sure you'll get lots of help getting through any of these smaller steps, and have fun doing so!